# Can't assign values to array of structs ansi c

Tags: arrays, struct, c89

Hi have defined this struct typdef:

```
typedef struct{
        int pid;
        int valor;
    }hijo;
```

But after reserving memory to it, I iterate the array to assign value to each struct, but values are not stored correctly:

```
hijo *retorno;
retorno=malloc(processes*sizeof(hijo));

while (processes > 0) {
        pid = wait(&status);
        int valors = WEXITSTATUS(status);
        retorno[i].valor=valors;
        retorno[i].pid=pid;
        --processes;  // TODO(pts): Remove pid from the pids array.
    }
```

Thanks.

Comment: ANSI-C is not standard C which the C tag implies. Said that: you should leave the 1990ies and use modern C. Best standard C which is C11, but at least C99.

Comment: What do you mean values are not stored correctly? Please post a MCVE; https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to initialize and increment `i`. Otherwise you keep assigning to the same array element.

```
hijo *retorno;
retorno=malloc(processes*sizeof(hijo));
int i = 0;

while (processes > 0) {
    pid = wait(&status);
    int valors = WEXITSTATUS(status);
    retorno[i].valor=valors;
    retorno[i].pid=pid;
    --processes;  // TODO(pts): Remove pid from the pids array.
    i++;
}
```

Or instead of updating two variables, you could just compare `i` to `processes`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < processes; i++) {
    pid = wait(&status);
    int valors = WEXITSTATUS(status);
    retorno[i].valor=valors;
    retorno[i].pid=pid;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

With this code, you are decremanting `processes` and you want assign value to retorno I guess. 
Then `retorno[i]` should be `retorno[processes]` right ?

Otherwise I don't understand what you want to do.

Comment: Should be `retorno[processes-1]` to prevent out-of-bounds access.

Comment: This looks more like a comment. Answers are not to comment. Get the reps first so you can write a comment.